# modular multiplicative inverse of $2 \pmod {17}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find an inverse of $a$ modulo $m$ for $a=2, m=17.$

Applying euclidian algorithm:

$\gcd(17,2)$

$17=8(2)+1$

$2=2(1)+0$

Expressed as a linear combination, this is $1=(1)17-8(2)$, and since the Bézout number associated with $a$ is $8$, the inverse should be $8$.  Wolfram tells me the answer is $9$. Where is my error?

Comment: The number is $-8$, not $8.$

Answer (score 3):

Your answer ($-8$) is correct, it's just that the generally preferred answer is the unique non-negative integer in the range $[0,16]$.

$(1)(17) + (-8)(2) = 1$

So the inverse is $-8 \equiv 9\mod{17} $

Comment: OP says that the inverse should be $8,$ not $-8.$ So the problem is that OP wants to know how to see that the inverse is actually $-8,$ instead of $8.$

Comment: I now understand that -8 is also a valid answer, and it makes perfect sense, thanks.  I feel like this is trivial, but what is the best way to determine the congruent answer in the preferred range, given -8 mod 18?

Comment: @awllower Ah, OK. But once he does the first division: $17 = (8)(2) + 1$, he can immediately rearrange that to $1 = (17)(1) + (-8)(2)$ and take the whole expression modulo $17$ to give $(-8)(2) \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$, which will immediately give the inverse as $-8 \equiv 9$.

Comment: @pha3l Again, by long divisoin: $-8=17(-1)+9$...Wait, where did you get $18?$